# Desing pattern for multiple combinations of a multiset (user roles)

Tags: java, design-patterns, multiset

I am facing trouble in deciding on better design pattern for the following usecase.

There are two modules in our project,

Moduel1, Moduel2

For a user to access each module, there are two sets of four entitlements: one set for Module 1 & the other for Module2.

Now, depending on the correct combination of the user role, I need to perform the logic specific to each module.

I have four user roles for module 1,

> Module1UserRole1, Module1UserRole2, Module1UserRole3, Module1UserRole4

Different combinations for this is 15.

For each of this combination i need to perform relevant logic.
Each logic is completely different from one another.

I am indecisive whether it is a good approach to put each combination logic 
in a separate class which gives readability instead of cramming up one single class with tons of  if and else conditions.

This gives me total 15 classes. (each class represents one combination of userrole)

Each of these classes will implement following interface viz. Module1UserRoles .

Given the above scenario,

1. Define Module1UserRoles interface
2. `public interface Module1UserRoles { executeModule1Logic(); }`

Lets say I am entitled to Module1UserRole1 && Module1UserRole2

Then the logic for the union of the above two roles will be written in **Moudle1UserRole1AndUserRole2Impl** .

```
public class Moudle1UserRole1AndUserRole2Impl Module1UserRoles {
    public void executeModule1Logic() {
///     implement the logic relevant userrole1 and userrole2.
    }
}
```

I am looking at various options. Any advice is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to go the way with 15 classes, as these classes are containing different code, not related to each other (as far as I understood). You will have 15 classes, implementing a common interface. The common interface should define all the methods, that the RoleLogic classes should implement.

Use a Factory-Pattern to determine the correct RoleLogic class to use. The return type of the factory will be the interface.

In your business logic, you can either use the RoleLogic as regular object and access it, or, if you already have a class for handling role dependend operations and you want to keep the signature of that class, use the RoleLogic Class als delegate.

Comment: Thanks Korashen. This is exactly we are implementing as of now. However if there is a new user role introduced (never know business requirements) then the combinations will be 31 and thus 31 classes.
And in the factory pattern the conditions grow as well for returning the correct implementation..Hopefully that should be fine ?!

Comment: If you encapsulate the distinctiv behaviour into their own classes, it will be _WAY_ easier to maintain them, trust me, I know what I'm talking there! ;-)
But there is another approach, you might want to consider. I don't know if you can really apply this:
If the roles have either similarities, or can be separated into different areas or groups (like "read access", "write access", "edit customers", or whatever), you can create classes, containing only the logic for a specific area and then use the factory to compose a RoleObject out of several PermissionObjects.

Comment: The application is receiving the entitlements from a webservice call...and i guess we are relying on an external interface and my knowledge on the roles setup ends there...Guess we will go with the approach we are currently following...
On a side note, we also thought of creating class for each NCR (N choose R)  combination which consists only the conditions for that subset (R) which essently means for 4 entitlements ( it is 4C1+4C2+4C3+4C4) for which we need to create only four classes instead of 15...again not sure how good that can be :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the key statement here is that, "Each logic is completely different from one another." If that's true, if *Moudle1UserRole1AndUserRole2* shares no logic with either *Module1UserRole1* or *Module1UserRole2*, then there would be no reason for, "cramming up one single class with tons of if and else conditions." In that case you're talking about a simple [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) with 15 possible algorithms.